# Always-On-SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, dial-up

We have a field office that uses a dialup connection with a non-public IP given from the ISP.

Dialin is done by GNOME-PPP.

How can we hold an SSH connection (with tunnel) open to a server in the Internet while the computer is connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autossh` is a tool (included in the Ubuntu repositories) which can automatically reconnect a SSH session. It can check via a separate if data is still being transmitted properly and reconnect the tunnel:

Here is a nice How-To:

http://pierre.linux.edu/2010/05/setting-up-a-permanent-ssh-tunnel-between-2-servers/

This can be combined with the `daemon` tool, to run in background.

Complete solution:

```
aptitude install autossh daemon
```

In `/usr/local/bin/autossh`

```
#!/bin/bash

AUTOSSH_POLL=600
AUTOSSH_PORT=20000
AUTOSSH_GATETIME=30
AUTOSSH_LOGFILE=autossh.log
AUTOSSH_DEBUG=yes
AUTOSSH_PATH=/usr/bin/ssh

HOST=example.com
USER=tunnel

autossh -M $AUTOSSH_PORT -N -L ... -R ... $USER@$HOST
```

Port forwardings have to be added instead of the "...". Actually everything after `-M $AUTOSSH_PORT` are SSH parameters.

And at the beginning of `/etc/rc.local` add

```
daemon -n autossh /usr/local/bin/tunnel
```